# oracle apex unable to create modules

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-apex-5.1

i am creating a oracle apex 5.1 application but for the last part after i press the create application button an error occured

Unable to create modules.
ORA-20001: Create pages error. ORA-20001: Unable to create report page. ORA-20001: Error page=13 item="P13__NULL_" id="" ORA-20001: Error page=13 item="P13__NULL_" id="" has same name as existing application-level item. ORA-0000: normal, successful completion

what was the error mean? how can i solve this?

note: i'm creating a classic reports with almost same source queries  gathered using query builder is this related to the problem?

Comment: Though it sounds weird, did you check to see if you have an application level item with the same name as the page level item by any chance? (P13_NULL)

Comment: application level item? columns?

Comment: i don't get what you mean

Comment: Application level Items can be found inside shared components.

Application -> Shared Components -> Application Logic -> Application Items.

Page level items are the items on the page ( in this case, it looks like the item is on page 13)